# Extract method in controller

Tags: extjs, listener, undefined

i have a controller that defines the handlers as functions:

```
init: function() {
        this.control({
            'wtToolbar menuitem[action=primario] menuitem[action=primer_anio]': {
                click: this.mostrarAbmAlumnos(1)
            },
            'wtToolbar menuitem[action=primario] menuitem[action=primer_anio]': {
                click: this.mostrarAbmAlumnos(2)
            },
            'wtToolbar menuitem[action=primario] menuitem[action=primer_anio]': {
                click: this.mostrarAbmAlumnos(3)
            },
            'wtToolbar menuitem[action=primario] menuitem[action=primer_anio]': {
                click: this.mostrarAbmAlumnos(4)
            },
            'wtToolbar menuitem[action=primario] menuitem[action=primer_anio]': {
                click: this.mostrarAbmAlumnos(5)
            },
            'wtToolbar menuitem[action=primario] menuitem[action=primer_anio]': {
                click: this.mostrarAbmAlumnos(6)
            }
       });
},
    /**
     * Muestra la ventana de gestion de un grado.
     * @param {int} idGradoSolicitado Id del grado a gestionar.
     * @return {void}
     */
    mostrarAbmAlumnos: function(idGradoSolicitado) {
        var store = Ext.create('AM.store.Alumnos', {}).load({
            params: {idGrado: idGradoSolicitado}
        });
        var grid = Ext.create('AM.view.grids.AbmAlumno', {dataStore: store});
        var win = Ext.create('AM.view.ui.WindowDecorator',
                {aTitle: 'Gestión de alumnos', anItem: grid});
        win.show();
    }
   /* End of controller */
});
```

so, i have two problems:

1) The window is created and shown 6 times in the load page.

2) When i click in the button that fires the envent, the next error is displayed in the console: TypeError: listener.fireFn is undefined

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the functions, instead of passing a function reference.

```
click: this.mostrarAbmAlumnos(1)
```

`this.mostrarAbmAlumnos(1)` doesn't return a function, that's what explains your TypeError.

Replace this line with that:

```
click: Ext.pass(this.mostrarAbmAlumnos, [1])
```

[`Ext.pass`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-pass) will create a new function that will call `this.mostrarAbmAlumnos` with the right argument. You can optionaly specify the scope (that is needed if you use the `this` keyword in the function used as event handler).

Now there's one last problem in your code. You're registering six times the same event. If you click on that button, the 6 windows will pop to your face. You need to add different menu items for each window ;)